# Configuring ILMerge package

Tags: c#, nuget, ilmerge

I have GUI c# project that has several additional packages in reference. I would like to have executable without any additional dll's in build output. For this purpose I'm trying to use `ILMerge` package from `nuget`. I have just installed package with command:

```
Install-Package ilmerge -Version 3.0.18
```

But as result I got same executable that requires dll's. Should I do any configuration in my project in order to make `ILMerge` package build merged executable?

Answer (score 1):

I can to propose to you another workaround, which works without any nuget packages, and just required some code:

1. You should add all references of your project as Embeded Resources.
2. After this in entrypoint of your app you should do next:

   ```
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolve;

   private Assembly OnAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
   {
       var assemblyName = args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(','));
       var assembly = ...load binary from embeded resources as you wish based on assemblyName...
       return Assembly.Load(assembly);
   }
   ```

profit: no additional packages. Easy to use and debug.

concern: hard to maintance if you have a lot of external packages. Needs to add them manually to Embeded Resources.

Comment: https://github.com/Fody/Costura - Same solution but automatically adds that code in to the main entry point and handles adding the packages as embedded resources ;)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i am pretty sure, that all ilmerge tools do same, but i prefer to control all stemp, if it's not cost to much. But anyway, thanks to your link =)

Comment: ILMerge actually modifies the original code of the dll to make it inside the exe. The problem with this is it breaks stuff like WPF's assembly names. The resource solution you and I show does not have the renaming problem. The comment I gave is just a way to automate it. *Fun Fact:* The author of ILMerge once said about using this embeding resources method "[... I think this is fantastic! If I had known about this, I never would have written ILMerge.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition/#comment-13163)"